General approach to overloading several similar functions
I have this pattern in my code:
public:
    int start(const uint32_t channel);
    int stop(const uint32_t channel);
    void set_current_desc(uint32_t channel, uint64_t cdesc);
    // ...
private:
    const uint32_t channel_;

All functions take in the channel argument. I would like to provide this interface:
public:
    int start(const uint32_t channel);
    int start(void) { return start(channel_); } 
    int stop(const uint32_t channel);
    int stop(void) { return stop(channel_); }
    void set_current_desc(uint32_t channel, uint64_t cdesc);
    void set_current_desc(uint64_t cdesc) { set_current_desc(channel_, cdesc); }
    // ...
private:
    const uint32_t channel_;

Is there a general approach to doing this for all functions at once, or will I have to type it all out? I guess there exists some messy macro method but I would prefer a C++ non-macro solution.
Edit: The initial interface must remain due to backwards compatibility.

have you considered using default function arguments instead of multiplying those functions?

From the little code we see, I'd say the problem is with the design. Why do you allow passing a different channel to method if it's a class member? Why doesn't user create a new instance of this class with a different channel if they want to operate on different channel?

make the parameter std::optional

Where are you setting channel_? Maybe expose a setter method to change its value, then you can avoid passing it to every function, just call the setter method (if needed) before calling any function.

@alagner: It looks like using channel_ as a default argument requires the member to be static. And I'm not sure I'm willing to do that.
@Yksisarvinen: I agree the design is non-optimal but I want the code to remain backwards compatible with earlier uses.
@kiner_shah: channel_ is set in the constructor's initializer list. But as mentioned above, I would prefer to keep the already existing interface for backwards compatibility.

no, there is no magic short cut. You could bind the parameter to the functions, but it will be no less typing than what you have right now

What is the range of values for channel?

It looks like using channel_ as a default argument requires the member to be static then use some special value to indicate the inner one should be used, e.g. make the default parameter optional and have nullopt server as the indicator the inner one should be used.
Or refactor that to get rid of the channel param altogether, should it be stored inside the class anyway.

This particular argument only takes on two values: 0 and 0x30.

I'm not quite sure I understand your approach @alagner. Could you show an example in code, perhaps?

Do you have many function names like that (each class has its own set) or few functions names (all classes have the same set)?

You can modify the methods to accept a std::optional with a default value of std::nullopt.
If the caller does not supply a channel (via the new interface) the channel_ member will be used.
If the caller supplies a channel (as you requested for backwards compatibility), it will be used.
This is done using the method std::optional::value_or.
#include <optional>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

class Test {
public:
    Test(uint32_t channel) : channel_(channel) {}

    void start(std::optional<uint32_t> channel = std::nullopt)
    {
        // Determine `cur_channel` to use:
        uint32_t cur_channel = channel.value_or(channel_);
        // Use `cur_channel` ...
        std::cout << "start, using channel: " << cur_channel << "\n";
    }
private:
    const uint32_t channel_;
};

int main() {
    Test test{ 333 }; // `channel_` member will be 333
    test.start();     // will use the `channel_` member of `test`
    test.start(5);    // will use 5 for the current channel (backwards compatibility)
}

Output:
start, using channel: 333
start, using channel: 5

Live demo
A similar approach can be used for the rest of your methods.

You can write a base class that has the channel_ overloads, but there is still a relatively large amount of boilerplate.
struct channel_ops {
    int start(this auto&& self) { return self.start(channel_); } 
    int stop(this auto&& self) { return self.stop(channel_); }
    void set_current_desc(this auto&& self, uint64_t cdesc) { self.set_current_desc(channel_, cdesc); }
protected:
    int channel_;
}

class foo: public channel_ops {
    // ...
public:
    int start(const uint32_t channel);
    using channel_ops::start;
    int stop(const uint32_t channel);
    using channel_ops::stop;
    void set_current_desc(uint32_t channel, uint64_t cdesc);
    using channel_ops::set_current_desc;
    // ...
};

Prior to C++23, you'd need to use CRTP:
template<typename Self>
struct channel_ops {
    int start() { return static_cast<Self*>(this)->start(channel_); } 
    int stop() { return static_cast<Self*>(this)->stop(channel_); }
    void set_current_desc(this auto& self, uint64_t cdesc) { static_cast<Self*>(this)->set_current_desc(channel_, cdesc); }
protected:
    int channel_;
}

class foo: public channel_ops<foo> {
    // ...
public:
    int start(const uint32_t channel);
    using channel_ops::start;
    int stop(const uint32_t channel);
    using channel_ops::stop;
    void set_current_desc(uint32_t channel, uint64_t cdesc);
    using channel_ops::set_current_desc;
    // ...
};


If you stay with this design, a possibility would be to use a default  conventional parameter value UNDEFINED and rely on it to know whether start is called without any argument.
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <cassert>

class foo
{
public:
    foo (uint32_t channel) : channel_(channel) 
    {
        // UNDEFINED_CHANNEL must be forbidden for channel_
        // otherwise infinite recursion could occur in 'start'
        assert (channel_ != UNDEFINED_CHANNEL);
    }
    
    int start (const uint32_t channel = UNDEFINED_CHANNEL)
    {
        // if no argument is provided, we use 'channel_'
        if (channel == UNDEFINED_CHANNEL)  { return start (channel_); }
        
        // do something here
        std::cout << "input: " << channel << "\n"; 
        
        return 0;
    }

private:
    const uint32_t channel_ {};
    
    static const uint32_t UNDEFINED_CHANNEL = std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max(); 
};

int main()
{
    foo x = 123;  
    
    x.start ();
    x.start (1);
    x.start (std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max());

    foo y = std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max();  // we should have an assert here
    y.start();
}

This is not perfect anyway since you should not use UNDEFINED as argument of start because it would use the channel_ member value instead.
You have also be sure that UNDEFINED cannot be used for channel_ otherwise you may have infinite recursion with start in case you provide no argument to it.
